# Comparing UIColors fails, but hashes are equal?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uicolor

I'm using UIColor to map to a value in a dictionary, but I bumped into a really odd thing. Half of my keys returns the right values, and the other half does not. When I compare the UIColors using isEqual they return false, but the hash matches just fine.

```
 for key in colorToAllocationCurrent.keys {
            print("\(key.hash) ---> \(currentColor!.hash)")
            print(key.isEqual(currentColor))
        }
```

This returns the following:

```
144048128 ---> 151431738
false
155123712 ---> 151431738
false
147739933 ---> 151431738
false
151431738 ---> 151431738 <-------- EQUAL?
false
```

Any ideas on why this goes wrong? I've checked to content of the UIColor, and they're the same.

When I print the description of the color instead of the hash, the colors appears the same again. The odd thing is that it work on half the colors.

```
 for key in colorToAllocationCurrent.keys {
            print("\(key.description) ---> \(currentColor!.description)")
            print(key.isEqual(currentColor))
        }

UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 ---> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.666667 0 1
false
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 1 0 1 ---> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.666667 0 1
false
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.333333 0 1 ---> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.666667 0 1
false
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.666667 0 1 ---> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.666667 0 1
false
```

Comment: Are the colors actually equal?  I am not sure but isEqual function might be checking the color values and not the hash.

Comment: Yea, the colors appear equal when I print them out.

Comment: As far as Hashes being equal and not the object check out this article   http://nshipster.com/equality/   It states that "However, the converse does not hold: two objects need not be equal in order for their hash values to be equal"  Can you print out the colors for which isEqual shows false.

Comment: I've updated my question. It seems like it is the Floats that bugs it.

Comment: Do you need to unwrap currentColor when passing it to isEqual?

Comment: Wow, I just tried not dividing by 255, and now it works. Apparently the comparison doesn't like float below 1?

Comment: That's Great!  Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! If anyone can elaborate on why this problem occurs with values below 1 in the UIColor, it would be great.

Comment: Please post the code where you are setting the color.  Will try to debug.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, it might make sense because when you divide the floating numbers might always be exactly the same.  Depends on the way it gets rounded.  Half the time it could be the same and have might be off slightly.  Try to debug to see the exact color values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure of the purpose of doing this, but you should note that [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) adopts [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor) which means that you can check the equality of `UIColor` instances by using `==`, for example:

```
let col1 = UIColor.red
let col2 = UIColor.red

// the output is "matched"
print(col1 == col2 ? "matched" : "no match")

let customCol1 = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 123.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9)
let customCol2 = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 123.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9)

// the output is "matched"
print(customCol1 == customCol2 ? "matched" : "no match")

let customCol3 = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 123.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9)
let customCol4 = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 123.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// the output is "no match"
print(customCol3 == customCol4 ? "matched" : "no match")
```