# How to compare UIColors in Swift

Tags: swift, colors, compare, equals

I'm trying to compare different colors in Swift. Everything is fine till i re-build the app. Same colors, same code, but it doesn't work.

I'm adding background color to a text, and I have different themes. When users change the theme the app should also change the background color for that theme. While using the app everything is fine, but when I rebuild the project it does not compare the colors as it should.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
for i in 0...noteTextView.attributedText.length-1
        {
            noteTextView.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(i,1), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
                    if let exValue = value as? UIColor
                    {
                        if(exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x2e3f4f))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xc0e1ff))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x2970ae))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xaad5fb)))
                        {
                            aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                            print("blue")
                            myValue = styles.blueHighlightColor()
                            self.noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                            saveChanges = true
                        }
                        else if (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xcafd70))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xbde970))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x568a56))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xbde970)))
                        {
                            aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                            print("green")
                            myValue = styles.greenHighlightColor()
                            self.noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                            saveChanges = true
                        }
                        else if (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x51445d))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x79569b))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb)))
                        {
                            aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                            print("pink")
                            myValue = styles.pinkHighlightColor()
                            self.noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                            saveChanges = true
                        }
                        else if (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xffffff))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xfbe769))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0x77745f))) || (exValue.isEqualWithConversion(UIColor(hex: 0xfbe769)))
                        {
                            aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                            print("yellow")
                            myValue = styles.yellowHighlightColor()
                            self.noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                            saveChanges = true
                        }
                    }
                }

        } // For loop end
```

I tried with '==' and also with this extension:

```
    extension UIColor
{
    func isEqualWithConversion(_ color: UIColor) -> Bool {
        guard let space = self.cgColor.colorSpace
            else { return false }
        guard let converted = color.cgColor.converted(to: space, intent: .absoluteColorimetric, options: nil)
            else { return false }
        return self.cgColor == converted
    }
}
```

Also if I use standard colors like UIColor.red or .blue or .green etc. it works fine.

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392256/comparing-uicolors-fails-but-hashes-are-equal) might be helpful...

Comment: @AhmadF it doesn't work

Comment: UIColor conforms to equatable Equatable so you can just say `if colorA == colorB`

Comment: I tried that... but still don't know why.. it doesn't work

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your *expected* results and the *actual* results. "It doesn't work." "...rebuild the app. Same colors, same code, but it doesn't work." Could you explain what you mean? I *may* have some help to give - if standard colors work, your code for RBG values may be off - but without an understanding of what "it doesn't work" means, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I needed:

```
 func compareColors (c1:UIColor, c2:UIColor) -> Bool{
    // some kind of weird rounding made the colors unequal so had to compare like this

    var red:CGFloat = 0
    var green:CGFloat  = 0
    var blue:CGFloat = 0
    var alpha:CGFloat  = 0
    c1.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

    var red2:CGFloat = 0
    var green2:CGFloat  = 0
    var blue2:CGFloat = 0
    var alpha2:CGFloat  = 0
    c2.getRed(&red2, green: &green2, blue: &blue2, alpha: &alpha2)

    return return (Int(red*255) == Int(red*255) && Int(green*255) == Int(green2*255) && Int(blue*255) == Int(blue*255) )


}
```

Comment: return (Int(red*255) == Int(red*255) && Int(green*255) == Int(green2*255) && Int(blue*255) == Int(blue*255) )

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the easiest way to compare `UIColors` is to convert them to `CGColors` because `CoreGraphics` has a method called `CGColorEqualToColor`.
For you comparison use

```
if(CGColorEqualToColor(Exvalue.CGColor, UIColor(hex: 0x2e3f4f).CGColor){
    //code stuffs
}
```

I am unable to check that the syntax is 100% correct (I am not currently at a computer), but you should be able to figure that out within xCode.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Xcode: CGColorEqualToColor is not available, instead use '=='

Comment: Then convert the colors to CGColors using UIColor.CGColor and compare them like that.  
like `UIColor.Blue().CGColor == UIColor.Green().CGColor`

Comment: The syntax is good, a little bit slower with the conversion to cgcolor but it works until I rebuild the project.

Comment: what do you mean rebuild the project? When does it work and when does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UIColor extension I use to get the RGB values, maybe it will help:

```
extension UIColor {
    func rgb() -> (Int?, Int?, Int?) {
        var fRed : CGFloat = 0
        var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
        var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
        var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
            let iRed = Int(fRed * 255.0)
            let iGreen = Int(fGreen * 255.0)
            let iBlue = Int(fBlue * 255.0)
            return (iRed, iGreen, iBlue)
        } else {
            // Could not extract RGBA components:
            return (nil,nil,nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let newTheme = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 30.2, green: 46.3, blue: 55.6, alpha: 1.0)
let newThemeRgb = newTheme.rgb()
let currentTheme = myView.backgroundColor
let currentThemeRgb = currentTheme.rgb()
        glClearColor(Float(rgb.0!)/256.0, Float(rgb.1!)/256.0, Float(rgb.2!)/256.0, 0.0);

if newThemeRgb.0 <> currentThemeRgb.0 || newThemeRgb.1 <> currentTheme.1 || newThemeRgb.2 <> currentThemeRgb.2 {
    //change view color
    myView.backgroundColor = newTheme
}
```